# AppInit_DLLs on Windows 7 (64 bit version)

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit, code-injection

I have written a DLL that will help me debug my app. I am running a 64 bit version of windows7. Here is what I am observing:

(1) If I set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs and run the 32 bit version of my application, the DLL gets loaded and everything is okay.
(2) If I set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs and run the 64 bit version of my application, the application starts but it crashes immediately.

Do you guys know any solution for this problem?

Comment: I am sorry. I just want to know if AppInit_DLLs feature is not supposed to work with 64 bit DLLs & 64 bit apps on win7

Comment: If you use Appinit_DLLs users will hunt you down and slap you around for loading terrible terrible code into all their programs....

Comment: @BillyONeal, in my case I had to use DLL injection and AppInit_DLLs to load a winsock "interposer" library. Why? Because Windows/Winsock consider: "Bind to this port on all addresses" and "Bind this port to this specific host address" to be 2 different binds. So, when you have a network service listening on port 49152 on all interfaces, and another process binds to {host IP address} port 49152, the latter steals the port from the former. It sucks.

Answer (score 2):

AppInit_DLLs can work for 64 bit apps on Win7, but you proably aren't meeting the requirements.

a) You probably need to know this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744762(v=VS.85).aspx.

b) If it is your app and your DLL, skip the whole AppInit_DLLs mechanism which is messy and usafe, and just do your own LoadLibrary at the right time.

Martyn

Answer (score 2):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs` is the registry key for the default CPU architecture, in your case 64-bit.

To hook a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS, use:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs`